# foursquare api - anyway to find original instagram post

Tags: api, foursquare, instagram, endpoints

I'm using the foursquare api to get photos for checkins. Its clear the source of a lot of these checkins is instagram.

When I pull the photo down, is there a way to get the original instagram url? Not just for the photo but the detail ie:

```
http://instagram.com/p/IZm_2Owxda/
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to retrieve the Instagram URL from the Foursquare API. You can try taking a look at Instagram's [locations/search](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/) endpoint to map a Foursquare venue ID to a Instagram location ID and see if this can somehow meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is an instagram api to [search for foursquare](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/) locations and then you can see all instagram photos posted at that location. There is an implementation in [gramfeed.com/instagram/places](http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/places) to do this search, look for foursquare locations and then look for instagram photos posted there